PTP accuracy vs timestamping method
Is there an order of magnitude guesstimate on how accurate of a time sync a PTP capable device can achieve given its packet timestamping method? I have an FPGA COTS board with a standard/non-1588-timestamping 100 Mbps PHY, but I have the freedom to create whatever MAC I want in the FPGA fabric (so I could implement Start-of-Frame timestamping). The more difficult approach would be for me to create a custom board with a IEEE 1588 timestamping phy.
To decide, I'd like to know how accurate of a timestamp each method can expect to achieve. Any experience with this?
